# Play a sound when moving cursor on a button?

Tags: unity, gui, audio

How to play a sound when moving a cursor on a button ?

Comment: -1 "does not show any research effort" What did you try? Do you have an issue with the mouse over detection? Do you have an issue with playing a sound? Do you want to play a one-shot sound or do you want the sound to repeat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unity has interfaces you can implement in order to detect when the pointer enters / leaves your UI element :

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;// Required when using Event data.

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour, IPointerEnterHandler // required interface when using the OnPointerEnter method.
{
    public AudioClip AudioClip ;
    private AudioSource audioSource ;

    //Do this when the cursor enters the rect area of this selectable UI object.
    public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        if( audioSource == null )
            audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        if( audioSource == null )
            audioSource = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();

        audioSource.PlayOneShot( AudioClip ) ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseOver.html) could help you. Add such an event to your button in the same manner as you add an OnClick() event. Let me know if it was helpful!

Comment: -1 How would they use the event; could you provide a code example? How is this linked to the fact that the OP wants to play a sound?